# font-weight is inconsistent?

Tags: php, css, html

EDIT: I'm really sorry I think I made a mistake. Now it is working as intended. The problem occured when I used `div` instead of `span`. I thought I changed and updated code, but apparently I didn't :(

I am new to HTML5/CSS and just getting into it. Today I ran into a problem concerning `font-weight` (I am using a web font). My PHP code looked like this:

```
echo '<p><strong>'.$name$.'</strong>, You made a reservation at <strong>'.$date.'</strong></p>'
```

and I have set CSS to (after CSS reset):

```
h1, p, input, table {
    font-family: "Noto Sans KR", serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

p {
    font-size: 12pt;
    line-height: 180%;
}

strong {
    font-weight: 500;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then everything was right. The texts inside the `strong` tag looked bold. Then I tried to apply ellipsis in `$name`, so I changed PHP code to:

```
echo '<p><span class="inform-name ellipsis"><strong>'.$name.'</strong></span>, You made a reservation at <strong>'.$date.'</strong></p>'
```

and set CSS to:

```
.inform-name {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 18em;
}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Then suddenly texts inside the `strong` tag does not look bold anymore. But `strong` tag is still applied. When I change `font-weight` to something like 800, text looks bold again, but other texts in `strong` (outside of `p`) looks even more thicker.

Does putting a `span` tag inside a `p` tag change something? I cannot understand what's happening here, and I tried searching but I couldn't find anything about this problem. Does anyone know why it's happening and how to fix it? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Lokks like use are missing `"` in this  line `<span class="inform-name ellipsis>` change this to `<span class="inform-name ellipsis">`

Comment: Oops sorry that's a typo in rewriting the code. It's not in the actual code.

Comment: Why would you use a p tag first, then a span tag and then a strong tag?

Comment: And i'm getting an error because of the double $ sign in the $name$

Comment: i thing u dont need css font-weight: 500; for strong, because strong its default to be bold

Comment: I'm really sorry, double $ was a typo rewriting code too :( I think I should close this question for now... I will double check everything.

Comment: delete span and apply class to strong as `<strong class="inform-name ellipsis"><strong>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking, but here is a solution that might help you with your problem

First I declared the two variables `$name` and `$date`

Then I removed the `span` tag.

This is the code:

PHP:

```
$name = 'John Johnson';
$date = '09-09-09';

echo '<p class="inform-name ellipsis"><strong>'.$name.'</strong>, You made a reservation at <strong>'.$date.'</strong></p>';

?>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .inform-name {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 18em;
}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

    h1, p, input, table {
    font-family: "Noto Sans KR", serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

p {
    font-size: 12pt;
    line-height: 180%;
}

</style>
```

And this is what I get from the code:

[image]